# how to scroll the scrollview after inserting textview?

Tags: iphone

I've a problem that I want to insert many lines in my scrollview from a textview but I want that after inserting 6 lines the scroll will be enabled not before it. please some one help me..

Answer (score 0):

Initially set the scrollEnabled property of the scrollView to NO, and set it to YES after inserting those six lines.

Comment: hi! thanx. but actually I also want that the size of scrollview will be increase according to no. of line and after certain no. of line scrolling will be enable and size will not increase

Comment: A scrollview has a contentView property whose size increases when you add content to it. You should increase the size of the frame that displays a portion of your scrollview. Don't increase the size of the frame once the upper limit is reached and enable scrolling then. (You can calculate the size of the reqd frame by doing lineHeight * no. of lines).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put a condition according to the number of characters. Roughly determine the number of characters in six lines. Store the textView text in a string and use the following condition:

```
NSString *textString = myTextField.text;

    if ( [textString length] < NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_IN_SIX_LINES )
    {

    [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];

    }

    else

    [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: hi! thanx. but actually I also want that the size of scrollview will be increase according to no. of line and after certain no. of line scrolling will be enable and size will not increase.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud set the scrollView's contentSize accordingly.

Assuming it's a vertical scroll, find the height of text/ scrollView and set it like this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(newHeight,width);
```